# Snowflake As of Join query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to do as of query in snowflake. i.e similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys.

TABLE A:

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | One | Three |
| 20 | One | Two |
| 10 | One | One |
| 05 | One | Five |

TABLE B:

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Two | Three |
| 10 | Two | One |
| 00 | Two | Zero |

Join TABLE A(Left) and TABLE B(Right) on Col_A and if there is a match then get the matched row, if there is no match then get the nearest row:

| COL_A(Left) | COL_B(Left) | COL_C(Left) | COL_A (Right) | COL_B(Right) | COL_C(Right) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | One | Three | 20 | Two | Three |
| 20 | One | Two | 20 | Two | Three |
| 10 | One | One | 10 | Two | Three |
| 05 | One | Five | 00 | Two | Zero |

Answer (score 3):

so with some CTE's to provide the data:

```
WITH table_a(col_a, col_b, col_c) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (30, 'One','Three'),
        (20, 'One','Two'),
        (10, 'One','One'),
        (05, 'One','Five')
), table_b(col_a, col_b, col_c) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (20, 'Two','Three'),
        (10, 'Two','One'),
        (00, 'Two','Zero')
)
```

then a cross join with a QUALIFY to throw away the not nearests:

```
WITH table_a(col_a, col_b, col_c) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (30, 'One','Three'),
        (20, 'One','Two'),
        (10, 'One','One'),
        (05, 'One','Five')
), table_b(col_a, col_b, col_c) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (20, 'Two','Three'),
        (10, 'Two','One'),
        (00, 'Two','Zero')
)
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    b.*
FROM table_a as a
CROSS JOIN table_b as b
QUALIFY row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs(a.col_a - b.col_a)) = 1
ORDER BY 1 desc;
```

gives unstables results, because 10 and 0 are the same distance from 5...

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C | COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | One | Three | 20 | Two | Three |
| 20 | One | Two | 20 | Two | Three |
| 10 | One | One | 10 | Two | One |
| 5 | One | Five | 10 | Two | One |

### Lets see why:

So given the abs(a-b) is equal, if we add a bias that is a tenth of the smallest value that will be in col_a col_b we can move the preference in one direction

```
SELECT a.col_a, b.col_a
    ,a.col_a - b.col_a as sub_1
    ,b.col_a - a.col_a as sub_2
    ,abs(sub_1) as abs_1
    ,abs(sub_2) as abs_2
    ,abs(sub_1+0.01) as abs_1b
    ,abs(sub_2+0.01) as abs_2b
    ,row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs_1) as rn_1_simple
    ,row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs_2) as rn_2_simple
    ,row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs_1b) as rn_1b
    ,row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs_2b) as rn_2b
FROM table_a as a
CROSS JOIN table_b as b
ORDER BY a.col_a desc, b.col_a desc
```

gives a lovely table:

| COL_A | COL_A | SUB_1 | SUB_2 | ABS_1 | ABS_2 | ABS_1B | ABS_2B | RN_SIMPLE | RN_SIMPLE | RN_1B | RN_2B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 20 | 10 | -10 | 10 | 10 | 10.01 | 9.99 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 30 | 10 | 20 | -20 | 20 | 20 | 20.01 | 19.99 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 30 | 0 | 30 | -30 | 30 | 30 | 30.01 | 29.99 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 20 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 10 | 10 | -10 | 10 | 10 | 10.01 | 9.99 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 20 | 0 | 20 | -20 | 20 | 20 | 20.01 | 19.99 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | 20 | -10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 9.99 | 10.01 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 | 10 | -10 | 10 | 10 | 10.01 | 9.99 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 20 | -15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 14.99 | 15.01 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 10 | -5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4.99 | 5.01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 5 | -5 | 5 | 5 | 5.01 | 4.99 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

we see that to get the sort order you implied we should use RN_2B which is `abs(b.col_a - a.col_a+0.01)`

So now with:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table_a as a
CROSS JOIN table_b as b
QUALIFY row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs(b.col_a - a.col_a+0.01))= 1
ORDER BY a.col_a desc;
```

we get

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C | COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | One | Three | 20 | Two | Three |
| 20 | One | Two | 20 | Two | Three |
| 10 | One | One | 10 | Two | One |
| 5 | One | Five | 0 | Two | Zero |

### Now lets talk about why that is bad

So if you have 100K+ rows this is ugly and you very much want to avoid this. The first thing is way to put an equi-join `(a.x = b. y)` on a JOIN/ON instead of the CROSS JOIN to limit the permutaions.

If you literally cannot do this you still for do the equi join in one stage, and then fill in the gaps with a LEFT JOIN

like this:

```
SELECT a.*,
    nvl(b.col_a, c.col_a) as col_a,
    nvl(b.col_b, c.col_b) as col_b,
    nvl(b.col_c, c.col_c) as col_c
FROM table_a as a
LEFT JOIN table_b as b ON a.col_a = b.col_a
LEFT JOIN table_b as c ON b.col_a is null
QUALIFY row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs(c.col_a - a.col_a+0.01))= 1
ORDER BY a.col_a desc
```

### hybrid:

mixing David's LAG/LEAD idea with my double join:

```
SELECT a.col_a, b.col_a, c.col_a
FROM table_a as a
LEFT JOIN table_b as b ON a.col_a = b.col_a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(col_a) over(order by col_a) as p_col_a,
        LEAD(col_a) over(order by col_a) as n_col_a
    FROM table_b
) as c ON b.col_a is null 
           AND a.col_a between nvl(c.p_col_a, a.col_a) and nvl(n_col_a, a.col_a)
ORDER BY a.col_a desc
```

gives:

| COL_A | COL_A | COL_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 |  | 20 |
| 20 | 20 |  |
| 10 | 10 |  |
| 5 |  | 0 |
| 5 |  | 10 |

shows how 10, 20 are match, 5 is pair with 2 values (1 above, 1 below) and 30 is only paired with one value below.

Then putting the QUALIFY on that:

```
SELECT a.*,
   nvl(b.col_a, c.col_a) as col_a,
   nvl(b.col_b, c.col_b) as col_b,
   nvl(b.col_c, c.col_c) as col_c
FROM table_a as a
LEFT JOIN table_b as b ON a.col_a = b.col_a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(col_a) over(order by col_a) as p_col_a,
        LEAD(col_a) over(order by col_a) as n_col_a
    FROM table_b
) as c ON b.col_a is null 
           AND a.col_a between nvl(c.p_col_a, a.col_a) and nvl(n_col_a, a.col_a)
QUALIFY row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by abs(c.col_a - a.col_a+0.01))= 1
ORDER BY a.col_a desc;
```

gives the expected results again, with the least amount of cross joins, row push through the row_number()

### New QUALIFY free:

So as per David's follow-up question, yes, this can be done but taking half range to the prior/next value on the to be joined table, and then breaking the tie with an extra check, I did it this way, as I am a real fan of BETWEEN but a non-between version could be done with only two checks.

```
SELECT a.col_a as aa,
   nvl(b.col_a, c.col_a) as col_a,
   nvl(b.col_b, c.col_b) as col_b,
   nvl(b.col_c, c.col_c) as col_c
FROM table_a as a
LEFT JOIN table_b as b ON a.col_a = b.col_a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(col_a) over(order by col_a) as p_col_a,
        LEAD(col_a) over(order by col_a) as n_col_a,
        (p_col_a+col_a)/2 as half_p_col_a,
        (n_col_a+col_a)/2 as half_n_col_a
    FROM table_b
) as c ON b.col_a is null 
            AND a.col_a between nvl(c.half_p_col_a, a.col_a) and nvl(c.half_n_col_a, a.col_a) 
            AND iff(c.half_p_col_a is null, true, a.col_a > c.half_p_col_a) -- tie breaker
ORDER BY a.col_a desc;
```

Comment: Can you get rid of the QUALIFY and the +0.01 logic just by changing your `a between x and y` to a `a >= x AND a < y`? That way it'll be an asymmetric comparison to handle the cases where a is exactly in the middle of x and y

Comment: @DavidGarrison so if a know it half way between b and lag_b it means it could pick just one side.  Ithe logic of how it pick needs sort (much like my +ve) and checking for behavior in neg values and crossing zero. But yes. I see how that could work…

Comment: @DavidGarrison I tried another way, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I think that's logically equivalent to what I had in mind. Makes for one less window function at least, which I generally expect to help performance. I appreciate the thoroughness of digging through this question ;)

Comment: Yes i suspect a union all of the two b table joins would give best performance on very large table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to join records from TABLE_A to the same ID column OR the next smallest ID column. This is a slightly rephrased question, but it's a much simpler answer.

```sql
with cte_b as (
    select
    COL_A, 
    lead(COL_A) over (order by COL_A) b.next_col_a
    COL_B,
    COL_C
    from table_b
)

SELECT
    a.COL_A,
    a.COL_B,
    a.COL_C,
    b.COL_A,
    b.COL_B,
    b.COL_C,
from table a
join cte_b b
    on a.COL_A >= b.COL_A and a.COL_A < b.next_col_a
```

This is simpler because you don't have to do the math on which ID is "closest" to a given ID, which can depend on the distribution of your IDs in the table.

---

If you REALLY NEED "closest" then you'll need to also include the lag as well as the lead.

```sql
lag(COL_A) over(order by COL_A) b.prev_col_a
```

and then implement your own logic on how to join. You'd need to do some more testing with your data, and decide how you want to handle edge cases (like the largest/smallest ID in your table)

I think you could find the averages between your IDs and it could look something like this.

```sql
ON a.COL_A >= ((prev_col_a + col_a) / 2) and a.COL_A < ((col_a + next_col_a)/ 2)
```

I do feel like there might be a more elegant answer out there on what the join condition should look like, but I haven't found one from a little bit of searching.

Answer (score 0):

there is a coming (PrPr) out-of-the-box solution provided by Snowflake: [Joining Time-Series Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/LIMITEDACCESS/asof-join)

```
SELECT *
FROM left_table l 
   ASOF JOIN right_table r
   MATCH_CONDITION (l.timestamp >= r.timestamp)
   ON l.id = r.id
ORDER BY l.id, l.timestampm, r.timestamp;
```